# why .hprof file generating in workspace

Tags: java, android

I am created a project in android studio and run smoothly.Some time  gradle take more time to build and showing  message gc over limit.Then .hprof file generated in my work-space(like below image).

It consumes huge size.Why this type of file generating?

[image]

Comment: Refer http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/samples/hprof.html

Comment: thanks  Balwinder Singh